# I can't find the error in my script

Tags: javascript

I am a student and cannot find the problem with this script.

Basically it needs to find an element(button) and click it, over and over again, but the only thing it does is filling up my memory.

```
var cybermy, timer;

function runscript(){
    cybermy=document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _4jy1 selected');
    for(var i=0;i<((cybermy.length)-5);i++){
    cybermy[i].click();
    }
return 0;

}


while(true){

timer=setTimeout(runscript, 20000);
}
```

I am not used to writing JavaScript, so the error might seem obvious, but I did try to find the answer and couldn't find it.

(This program is written for pushing the poke button on Facebook. This is for educational purpose only.)

Comment: while(true)...congrats on making an infinite loop.

Comment: Ya why is that while even there? Take that out and runscript should resolve everything?

Comment: I can't see a while(true) without a chill..

Comment: you dont need the setTimeout...just do while(true) runscript();

Comment: Have you made sure that you're selecting the right element? Why are you looping through the indexes like that?

Comment: This might be a late reaction, but as i said i didn't have any experience with javascript. I was assuming setTimeout was a pause function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing your while(true) block. Instead, just setInterval so runscript will run on an interval

Instead of this:

```
while(true){
  timer=setTimeout(runscript, 20000);
}
```

Try this

```
timer = setInterval(runscript, 20000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `while(true)` and use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval

Answer (score 0):

Remove the while(true) and what's in it instead use the setInterval(func, interval) method with the same parameters as your code inside the while loop.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat something, then please try the above code using

```
setInterval(runscript, 20000)
```

setTimeout() simply invokes after the said amount of milliseconds only once, whereas setInterval as the name implies keeps on invoking after the said milliseconds.